# Prestashop products url ends .html

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

In Prestashop I using SEO & URL and in settings on the "route to products" looks like this: `{id}-{rewrite}.html` and my url looks like:

```
www.example/12-product1.html
```

And if i delete from "route to products" .html my url open like this:

```
www.example/12-product1
```

But now the site not found. How I understand, now I need to change the URL without .html end in database?

Comment: Try following solution, it is from PrestaShop forge:

http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-6542

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the .html of the product rewrite rule it will conflict with the default category rewrite. To avoid this, change the category rewrite, maybe adding another - between id and the name.